# Isekai manga where the main character is summoned by the goddess of time, then abandoned and picked up by another goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Looking for the name of a manga where the main character is summoned by the goddess of time, then abandoned because of low potential, and then picked up by another goddess.

Comment: This is a pretty generic description. Can you add any more useful info?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?  Do you remember any details of the art or the cover?  Any character names?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Is this the series where the MC ends up using logs as his weapon?

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[Hero of God Eye](https://anilist.co/manga/100213/Shingan-no-Yuusha)* (Shingan no Yuusha)?

> Makoto is a recluse (hikikomori) who gets summoned to another world. But the Goddess of Time and Space, Astena insults [him] and [calls] Makoto a failure [because of his] low stats. The Goddess throws Makoto in the wilderness. After he meet an old woman who asks for food and reveals herself to Makoto as a Goddess Liana, who controls the ... *"God's Eye."*