# Manga where the main character was abandoned by a goddess and thrown in an unknown place

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

As far as I remember, the protagonist became overpowered and has a harem. Also, it was shown that the main character's (MC) future self had a relationship with the goddess and they had a daughter/son. The daughter/son came back to the past to fix the relationship between the goddess and the MC at that time. Also, the goddess may have had the power to control time.

It's not *Failure Frame* or *Moon-led Journey*.

Comment: [This maybe?](https://tsukimichi.fandom.com/wiki/Makoto_Misumi)

Comment: Is this full color or black and white? Do you remember about where in the story the goddess's child appears? Do you remember anything about the MC's powers? Or the appearance of the MC, the goddess, or any of the other girls with the MC? Any idea what year you read this?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Brave with God's eyes](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shingan-no-yuusha)*, aka *Shingan no Yuusha*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264272/102326).

> Makoto is a recluse (hikikomori) who gets summoned to another world. From the Goddess Liana, he's granted the "Truth Eye" aka "God's Eye". Makoto is now able to see various things, including the past and future, using this ability to live as an adventurer in a different world.

As mentioned in the linked question, he is initially summoned by the goddess of time and space (Astenia), but abandoned. A second goddess (Liana) grants him powers.

The scene with his daughter is in chapter 31.

[image: Daughter]

He is abruptly taken to a different area at the end of chapter 30, with a girl calling him Father. Chapter 31 expands on this and has her stating that he and her mother initially have a bad relationship, so she doesn't want to say her name or her mother's name to avoid (further) souring their relationship.

[image: Awful relationship with mother]

He realizes that this is because her mother is the goddess from the first chapter, since she's the goddess of time.